# How is Nightmare Difficulty Different in Orcs Must Die?

Tags: orcs-must-die

I just finished beating Orcs Must Die! in the middle difficulty. I was considering playing through in nightmare mode, but I don't care to if it is all the same levels. How is nightmare different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is all the same levels.  However, they are significantly more difficult because:

- The enemies that spawn are significantly more difficult *(more heavy orcs, ogres, etc)*
- Your traps and weapons do less damage
- There is no wait time between rounds

Comment: Also, you have a chance to receive another 5 skulls per level to spend on upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

Same levels, as mentioned.

To expand on nightmare, the [Orcs Must Die wiki page](http://orcsmustdie.wikia.com/wiki/Nightmare_Mode) mentions that the changes in this difficulty are:

- Decreased **player health** by 50%
- Decreased **rift points** by 50%
- Increased **Mob health** by 20%
- Increased **Mob damage** by 20%
- Orc Warriors have **Shields**
- **Guardians** receive 20% **less damage**.
- **All breaks** between waves (including at the start of the stage, before the first wave is unleashed) **are only 3 seconds long**.